# Swift Compiler performance

Tags: performance, swift

I got this statement in Swift code which produces an error when executing in playground:

```
let colors: [String: [Float]] = ["skyBlue" : [240.0/255.0, 248.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0,1.0], 
"cWhite" : [250.0/255.0, 250.0/255.0, 250.0/255.0, 1.0]]
```

The error is : `expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

Then I changed the arrays element type to `Double` which just works fine.

However I am asking myself why this happens ?
As I said using `Double` it works just fine. So my guess is that Swift tries to guess the type and therefore `Double` works better in this example than `Float`.

Comment: Similar issues have been reported before, and (as I understand it) the problem is always the automatic type inference. You should file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But if the type inference is the problem here it isn't really a bug which is solvable, right ? Because the problem isn't my list but the model of type inference in general. Because this list could be expanded with more complexity infintely.

Comment: The types can be inferred from the context, and it works for a dictionary of a single color, therefore I would consider it a bug (but I am not a compiler expert). – In this concrete case you can work around it by converting each number in the array to a  Float explicitly: `[Float(240.0/255.0),  ...`.

Comment: Ok thank you. This would dramatically decrease readability but looks like the right way to go. I really would like to give you credit for that. So if you would provide it as an answer I could accept your answer. Thanks however :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar issues have been reported before, and (as I understand it) the problem is the automatic type inference for "complicated" expressions. You should file a bug report at Apple.

It compiles with a dictionary of one color, but not with two.

In this concrete case, you can work around it by converting each number in the array to a Float explicitly:

```
let colors = [
    "skyBlue" : [Float(240.0/255.0), Float(248.0/255.0), Float(255.0/255.0),Float(1.0)], 
    "cWhite" : [Float(250.0/255.0), Float(250.0/255.0), Float(250.0/255.0), Float(1.0)]
]
```